# Zend Framework - view object set in bootstrap not available in view phtml files

Tags: zend-framework, view, bootstrapping

I have been trying to set an object in the Bootstrap.php file and would like to be able to use this in all view phtml files.

As an example I set up Zend_Translate in an _init function as follows:

```
function _initTranslations() {
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();

    $translate = new Zend_Translate('gettext', 
                                    APPLICATION_PATH.'/languages',
                                    null,
                                    array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_FILENAME));
    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('translation'); // get session to check if user set lang
    $locale = new Zend_Locale();
    if (isset($session->language)) {
        // if user has previously set the lang we use this setting
        $requestedLanguage = $session->language;
        $locale->setLocale($requestedLanguage);
    } else {
        // otherwise we use the browser's setting
        $locale->setLocale(Zend_Locale::BROWSER);
        $requestedLanguage = key($locale->getBrowser());
    }
    if (in_array($requestedLanguage, $translate->getList())) {
        $language = $requestedLanguage;
    } else {
        $language = 'en';
    }
    Zend_Registry::set('locale', $locale);
    $translate->setLocale($language);
    $view->translate = $translate;
}
```

I would have thought that the $view->translate = $translate; would be sufficient to make the $translate object available in my views but it can only be accessed in my layout.phtml

Am relativley new to Zend Framework and suppose this issue has come up to others before but my internet research did not give me an answer so I was hoping someone here could point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to set Zend_Translate to Zend_Registry in Bootstrap and you ca use translate view helper in any phml.

Put this line at the end:

```
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for the answer! This would mean that I would have to get it out of the Zend_Registry in every view, right? As it will be used in all views, I was hoping for a way that would make $translate available in all views straight away without having to initialize it every time.

Comment: No, you do not need to initialize it just use translate view helper.
E.g  try some like this in phtml

<?php echo $this->translate("Label");?> 

And that should print out translation of label. 
More about this helper you can find on 

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html

Comment: And what if I just want to print the language in the html lang property on the layout file?

Answer (score 0):

Although you have found your answer, you can access the view resource in your bootstrap with the follow:

```
$this->bootstrap('view');
$view = $this->getResource('view');
```